# Matlab code 5 msec timer

Tags: matlab

Can any tell me how i can write a 5 msec timer code in matlab ?

%% Decomposing into sets of 40 bytes packets

% While Time < T1(= 5 msec), keep on filling the 40 bytes-sized packet

```
    %while(Total_Connection_Time-Running_Time)>0   
    for n=1:length(total_number_of_bytes)
    % n=counter to go through "total_number_of_bytes" marix
    packets=[]; % 40-bytes matrix (packetization phase)

     % checking whether number of bytes at each talkspurt period is < or > 40 bytes in order to start packetization
    if (total_number_of_bytes(n)<=40)
    k=40-total_number_of_bytes(n); % calculating how many remaining bytes we need to complete a 40 bytes packet
    packets=[packets,total_number_of_bytes(n)+k];
    total_number_of_bytes(n)=40; %new bytes matrix after packetization (adding bytes from next talkspurt to get total of 40 bytes)
    total_number_of_bytes(n+1)= total_number_of_bytes(n+1)-k; % bytes are taken from the next talkspurt period in order to get a 40 byte packet

    if  total_number_of_bytes(n+1)<0
        for i=1:length(total_number_of_bytes) % looping through the array starting total_number_of_bytes(n+1)
            total_number_of_bytes(n+1)=total_number_of_bytes(n+1)+total_number_of_bytes(n+1+i)
            total_number_of_bytes(n+1+i)=0;
            packets=[total_number_of_bytes]
        end 
    end 
end

if(total_number_of_bytes(n)>40)
    m=total_number_of_bytes(n)-40; % cz we need 40 bytes packets
    packets=[packets,total_number_of_bytes -40];
    total_number_of_bytes(n)=40;
    total_number_of_bytes(n+1)= total_number_of_bytes(n+1)+m; % The remaining bytes are added to the next talkspurt period bytes
    packets=[total_number_of_bytes]
end
```

Comment: Do you want to only write one 5ms block?  If so, put a `tic` at the beginning and check the value of toc at the beginning of each loop.  If you need it repeated at precise 5 ms intervals, then using the timer functionality with callbacks is the best approach.

Comment: You will not be able to get close to millisecond accuracy with `tic` and `toc`, `timer`, or MATLAB in general.

Comment: @dustincarr I'm sure that standard deviation may be well be small, but I don't see how that's relevant. You've run some tic/tocs a bunch of times and asked them to stop when their reported times are very close to 0.005. Of course the answers you get will all be very close to 0.005 - you've designed things to achieve that. Nevertheless, the times reported by `tic` and `toc` are not accurate to within milliseconds.

Comment: @SamRoberts, I didn't realize that. Can you provide a reference on that?

Comment: @dustincarr I apologise - please ignore my previous comments. I was unaware of this, but it turns out that in R2008b `tic` and `toc` were completely reimplemented, and the accuracy vastly improved from what was previously a large number of milliseconds to what is apparently now around a microsecond. Very good. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18510-matlab-performance-measurement

Comment: @SamRoberts thanks a bunch for looking into that and clarifying the issue.

Answer (score 1):

for better accuracy use

```
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(5);
```

instead of tic toc, see more [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/pause-for-the-better) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Tic and toc are getting a bad rap, so I will just post this.

I tried the following:

```
tic
count = 0;
while toc<0.005
    a=randn(10);
    count = count+1;
end
toc
```

Running it ten times, the maximum value of toc was 5.006 ms.  The count was around 1000 each time.

This is not the same as your program, but if graphics or GUI are not involved, I think tic and toc can do the job.